# how to decide whether two persons are connected

Tags: algorithm, graph

Here is the problem:

assuming two persons are registered in a social networking website, how to decide whether they are connected or not?

my analysis (after reading more): actually, the question is looking for - the shortest path from A to B in a graph. I think both BFS and Dijkstra's Algorithms works here and time complexity is exactly the same (O(V+E)) because it is an unweighted graph, so we can't take advantage of the priority queue. So, a simple queue could resolve the problem. But, both of them doesnt resolve the problem that: find the path between them.

Bidrectrol should be a better solution at this point.

Comment: DFS will yield... interesting results. Alice knows Bob. Alice also knows Carol, who knows Dave, who knows Eve, who knows Bob. DFS is equally likely to return Alice->Carol->Dave->Eve->Bob as it is Alice->Bob. :)

Answer (score 3):

To find a path between the two, you should begin with a breadth first search. First find all neighbors of `A`, then find all neighbors of all neighbors of `A`, etc. Once `B` is hit, not only do you have a path from `A` to `B`, but you also have a **shortest** such path.

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) rocks, and you may be able to speed this up by working from both end, i.e. find neighbors of `A` and neighbors of `B`, and compare.

If you do a depth first search, then you're following one path at a time. This will be much much slower.

Comment: Both DFS and BFS will have O(N+M) complexity, so this isnt such a big difference.

Comment: The average time for DFS is far worse. It's really a question of balancing time vs space.

Comment: Working from both ends is a good idea in real social networks, as most paths are very short. It's also an idea that is actually used in some systems.

Comment: For a large graph like social networking, BFS/DFs alone wouldn't be any good. You **have** to use heuristics.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use *Union Find*, add all links `union(from,to)`, and if `find(A) is find(B)` is True then `A` and `B` are connected. This avoids the recursive search but it actually computes the connectivity of all pairs and doesn't give you the paths that connects `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do dfs for finding whether two people are connected on a social network, then it will take too long!

You already know the two persons, so you should use [Bidirectional Search.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search). But, simple bidirectional search won't be enough for a graph as big as a social networking site. You will have to use some heuristics. Wikipedia page has some links to it.

You may also be able to use [A* search.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) From wikipedia : "A* uses a best-first search and finds the least-cost path from a given initial node to one goal node (out of one or more possible goals)."

**Edit:** I suggest A* because "The additional complexity of performing a bidirectional search means that the A* search algorithm is often a better choice if we have a reasonable heuristic." So, if you can't form a reasonable heuristic, then use Bidirectional search. (Forming a good heuristic is never easy ;).)

Comment: I doubt you could use A* to be fair. A* only works if you've got a heuristic that never overshoots. How would you construct such a heuristic for a social network?

Comment: @biziclop : From wiki: "The additional complexity of performing a bidirectional search means that the A* search algorithm is often a better choice if we have a reasonable heuristic." If you can't form a resonable heuristic, then use bidirectional search!

Comment: Reasonable isn't enough for A*, as I said your heuristic must be admissible. I can't see any way you can formulate any non-trivial admissible heuristics for this problem.

Comment: A* is used for finding the path, so if you your heuristic is admissible then it never overlooks the optimal path. But here, the question is just to verify whether they are connected or not, so even a sub-optimal path would work. Also, for designing a heuristic, i would have to know about the structure of the social networking site for which i have to write this code, the necessary information that is made available to me,etc. Also, i don't know why you are overlooking my first choice for this type of problem, i.e, Bidirectional Search. If you can form an admissible heuristic use A*, else don't

Comment: The reason I'm overlooking the first part is that there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @biziclop : I added your concern to my answer. I agree that forming an admissible heuristic for this problem is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the true criteria is: there are at least N paths between A and B shorter then K, or A and B are connected diectly.  I would go with K = 3 and N near 5, i.e. have 5 common friends.

Comment: Could you explain why this got -1? According to [Six degrees of separation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) two persons will be connected anyway. The question is are they connected enough.

Comment: Ah! I was searching for this, but couldn't find it. Its a good theory, can be used for heuristics, but imposing bounds wouldn't be good for this problem. Also, N can be zero, that means they are not connected. +1 for creativity :).

Answer (score 0):

**Note: answer edited.**

Any method might end up being very slow.  If you need to do this repeatedly, it's best to find the connected components of the graph, after which the task becomes a trivial O(1) operation: if two people are in the same component, they are connected.

Note that finding connected components for the first time might be slow, but keeping them updated as new edges/nodes are added to the graph is fast.

There are several methods for finding connected components.

One method is to construct the Laplacian of the graph, and look at its eigenvalues / eigenvectors.  The number of zero eigenvalues gives you the number of connected components.  The non-zero elements of the corresponding eigenvectors gives the nodes belonging to the respective components.

Another way is along the following lines:

1. Create a transformation table of nodes.  Element `n` of the array contains the index of the node that node `n` transforms to.
2. Loop through all edges `(i,j)` in the graph (denoting a connection between `i` and `j`):

   - Compute *recursively* which node do `i` and `j` transform to based on the current table.  Let us denote the results by `k` and `l`.  Update entry `k` to make it transform to `l`.  Update entries `i` and `j` to point to `l` as well.
3. Loop through the table again, and update each entry to point *directly* to the node it *recursively* transforms to.

Now nodes in the same connected component will have the same entry in the transformation table.  So to check if two nodes are connected, just check if they transform to the same value.

Every time a new node or edge is added to the graph, the transformation table needs to be updated, but this update will be much faster than the original calculation of the table.

Comment: Isn't that a bit too much for simply finding the shortest path between two specified nodes?

Comment: Checking connection between 2 nodes have a very little in common with finding connected components of graph.

Comment: @biziclop, no, it depends on what tools you already have available.

Comment: This is not what his question boils down to. This is a way to solve the problem for all `A` and all `B` simultaneously. It's complete overkill for a single pair `A` and `B`.

Comment: @PengOne @kilotaras If you don't cache connected components, finding if two nodes are connected is going to be very slow.  If you do cache connected components, updating them later when the graph changes is fast.

Comment: Finding `Strongly connected components` would be better. However, this is a searching problem, and this is just overkill. Also, the size of connected components will be _huge_. This method wouldn't be superior to any brute force searching method.

Comment: @logic_max the OP didn't say he has a directed graph, so I'm not sure why you talk about strongly connected components.

Comment: @Szabolcs : OP didn't say directed graph either, did he? Twitter is a social networking website, in which A->B does not means that B->A. The same goes for the new Google+. So, i assumed it is a directed graph.